# node.js - Upload image to MySQL table

Tags: html, image

Hello I am having issues displaying images uploaded to MySQL. My table looks like so.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images(id int primary key auto_increment,
  image_id varchar(255) NOT NULL, img LONGBLOB NOT NULL);
```

I handle the uploaded image on my server like so

```
 const multer = require('multer');
 const upload = multer({ dest: `static/images/product_images/` });       

 app.post('/upload-image', upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
  const img = req.file; 

  fs.readFile(img.path, (err, data) => {
   connection.query(`
          INSERT INTO product_images(product_id, img)
                    VALUES(?,?)`,
                    [
                        randomId(),
                        data
                    ],
                    (err, results) => {
                      //etc...
          });
      });
     });
```

Now if I fetch that image it looks like this

```
 "img": {
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    255,
    216,
    255,
    224,
    0,
    16,
    74,
    70,
    etc..
     ]
    }
```

Am I doing this correctly? When I fetch that image and try to display it on the front end using

```
 <img src='img-blob'/>
```

It doesn't display the image. What am I doing wrong?

I know uploading images to the db is considered a bad idea by some but I have no other choice

Answer (score 1):

There's a special syntax you should use to have an image inline in the source.  I pulled this from the following SO question:

[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

```
<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this error data:image/png;base64, 255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,237,0,108,80,104,111,116,111,115,104 etc... net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Yep that did it! Thank you!

Comment: How did you converted this buffer data to base64?

Comment: A quick google search yields a [link to the documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64).